# TSQLConnection connection editor dialog at run time?

Tags: sql, database, delphi, vcl

If I double click a TSQLConnection at design time I get a dbExpress connections dialog allowing me to select connections or create new ones.

Is there anyway to use that connections dialog at run time ? I would love to present it to my users so they can select a connection.

That particular dialog looks more useful to me than PromptDataSource.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way. This editor is located in DBConnEd unit, which is linked into dcldbXxx.bpl. And this package is Delphi design-time package. So, you cannot use it at run-time. Also, this editor is not accessible in D2009 and D2010.

Comment: Is there an alternative or equivalent functionality somewhere else ?